# Mysql communication error in tomcat even with out using any mysql in application

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I am Getting following error when ever i am starting my tomcat

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused
```

I am getting this error even with out using any application in my tomcat.

Could you please help me why tomcat is looking for mysql connect at the time of start
Regards

Comment: import mysql connector jar in your server program and client program

Comment: Hi If i am not using any myqsl db in application then why i need this mysql connector jar

Answer (score 1):

May be *you have configured a Tomcat Datasource Resource in your server.xml or context.xml* in your `${CATALINA_BASE}/conf` directory. So, whenever tomcat starts it tries to create the connection pool for your datasource and *it is not able to communicate to the db server host*. This is highly possible if you don't use mysql in your application